How to light my magic chef oven model #cly1631bdh
Rv oven
Model cly1631bdh
Serial number 13357478wy

Look online for the instructions, if you do not have them.

I did look couldn't find them

Try searching with  magic chef rv oven(or stove).

Magic Chef has a chat at https://mcappliance.com/magic-chef -- you could try using that to ask them directly.  Alternately, you could try uploading pictures.  Any knobs, cooktop down, cooktop up.

What's the actual problem?  No gas flow?  Burners don't light when you turn the knob?
